# Does google cloud platform supports nodejs?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I want to create an App, in which at backend I want to write code on node.js does google cloud platform supports node.js ?

I can see only Python,Java,PHP and GO are supported.

[image]

Comment: you are confused between appengine and cloud plattform. not the same.

Answer (score 1):

Google appengine does not officially support node.js. However you can run node.js in a managed VM.

[This quickstart project on github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-nodejs-quickstart) explains the basics.

Also

- [why is javascript node.js not on google app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450321/why-is-javascript-node-js-not-on-google-app-engine) and
- [Is it possible to develop a Google App Engine web app using Node.js or some other server side JavaScript approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927199/is-it-possible-to-develop-a-google-app-engine-web-app-using-node-js-or-some-othe)

have some very useful information you should read.

There is however official support for node.js in combination with google cloud, but that is not appengine. See https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/getstarted/start_nodejs/ for more information about that